# Udev Rules and script issues

Tags: shell, usb, udev

So I want to make a udev rule which does, when I connect my usb key to my computer the rule mounts my usb key, takes a file from my computer, copies it to my usb key and then unmounts my usb.
So I did my udev rule like that:

```
ACTION=="add" SUBSYSTEM=="BLOCK", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="0718", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="0618", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="CB00524932077759", RUN+="/bin/mount /dev/sda1 /media/usb"
ACTION=="add" SUBSYSTEM=="BLOCK", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="0718", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="0618", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="CB00524932077759", RUN+="/bin/ScriptCopy"
```

And I wrote a script, in /bin, called ScriptCopy:

```
#!/bin/sh

cp /root/average.db /media/usb/database/average.db

ldconfig

echo "Done!"
exit 0
```

So the first part of my udev rule works, it mounts the usb key, but then my script does not work, I do not really understand why. Can someone explain it to me? Thx

edit 1:
when I am running my script in the terminal, doing

```
./ScriptCopy
```

it works! so I must have a problem in my udev rule.

edit 2:
I found out something really strange (at least, that I don't understand at all), my rule works if I am plugging my USB key while I am on the GUI (XFCE) on my banana pi. But I am working with ssh, so normaly I don't open the GUI. I want to do is, to run some commands with the ssh, trigger my python script and then I take the data with my usb key once every two days. But when I plug my usb while banana pi is not on the GUI (while I triggered my script from another computer using ssh), it does not transfert the data to my usb key. I don't know if it was understandable.

Edit 3:
Ok I had an error of path in my UDEV rule because on ssh, I was not in the same user. I am closing the topic.

Comment: Why do you end your script with a `done` statement? To the best of my knowledge this defines the end of a loop, which you don't have. Exit the script using `exit 0`. The `0` defines a successful execution. Although this will probably not solve your issue.

Comment: Yes you right! My bad, but yes it does not solve my problem neither.

Comment: no error messages? Also, can you use `#!/bin/bash` at top instead? To see debug mode, use `set -vx` before your `cp` command. AND have you created your `database/` dir on your USB? Finally, if you created script anywhere near MS Windows, do `dos2unix ScriptCopy`. Good luck.

Comment: I forgot to say it, but I am working on bananian (debian for banana pi). And yes I have this directory on my USB. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had an error of path in my script/udev rule.